# How to mock a FileProvider in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have a unit test that looks like this :

```
public class MyFileProviderTest {
  private readonly MyFileProvider subject;
  private readonly Mock<IFileProvider> fileprovider = new Mock<IFileProvider>;

  public MyFileProviderTest {
    subject = new MyFileProvider(fileprovider.Object)
  }

  [Fact]
  public void GetAssets(){
     fileprovider.Setup(x => x.GetDirectoryContents(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new ?????);
  }
}
```

What should ????? be ?. I cannot find a proper example in Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you're going to test. I mean `GetDirectoryContents` is supposed to return an object of type which implements `IDirectoryContents` which in turn "implements" `IEnumerable<IFileInfo>`. The `IDirectoryContents`  interface itself declares single property - `Exists`. So that you may want to return an object of type with mocked `Exists` method or `GetEnumerator` method or both of them.

You can take the following as an example and then edit depending what you're going to test:

```
[Fact]
public void GetAssets()
{
    var directoryContentsMock = new Mock<IDirectoryContents>();
    directoryContentsMock.Setup(dc => dc.GetEnumerator()).Returns(new List<IFileInfo>().GetEnumerator());
    directoryContentsMock.Setup(dc => dc.Exists).Returns(false);

    fileprovider.Setup(x => x.GetDirectoryContents(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(directoryContentsMock.Object);
}
```